# It's possible to create dump of mysql container from other container?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have Spring Boot application that does mysql dump from docker container

```java
DOCKER_CLIENT.listContainersCmd()
             .withNameFilter()
             .exec()
```

now i have to run spring boot app and mysql docker base separately. I know that when I run with docker-compose java app and mysql, then docker-client will not work because it works on my system. There is a way for the contener application to see the second contener and do a database dump?

Answer (score 4):

[mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) takes the usual `--host` and `--port` options.  There's no requirement to run it from "the same context" as the database, and there's no need to use the extremely dangerous `docker exec` path you suggest.

This means you can tell `mysqldump` to connect to the database the usual way you'd tell any other application to connect to it.  Say your `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8
    ports: ['3307:3306'] # note different host and container ports
    ...
  application: { ... }
```

From the host you could run

```sh
mysqldump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3307 the_database > some-host-file.sql
```

If you really couldn't install the standard MySQL tools on your host, it would probably work to

```sh
docker-compose run --rm mysql \
  mysqldump --host database the_database \
> some-host-file.sql
```

Note that your host's shell captures the redirection before `docker-compose run` starts, so the destination file here is on the host system and not in a container.  Also note that, since this launches a temporary container and makes an inter-container connection, it uses the standard database port and you don't need to manually set `--port`.

Comment: (Anyone who can access the Docker socket can trivially root the entire host.  If your application has access to the Docker socket to exec additional processes in the database container, it can also run a container that bind-mounts the host's `/etc` directory and do whatever it wants there.  I'd avoid using the Docker API in your application if at all possible, and in general would avoid using `docker exec` when alternatives exist.)

Comment: thanks, but I can't run from host : mysqldump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3307 the_database > some-host-file.sql

I have to create database backup from application level (and restoring it), and I want to run it in docker

Comment: The second approach of running `mysqldump --host database`, using the other container's Compose service name as the database host name, should work in this setup.  You would need the `mysqldump` client tool installed in your application image's Dockerfile.